# Caching Android WebViews vs Embedding All JavaScript/CSS Into HTML

Tags: android, angularjs, webview

I'm looking into ways to improve the load speed of my AngularJS WebView app. For whatever reason, there is about a 4 second wait of white screen as the application loads.

While most of the wait is due to back end settings, I am looking to optimize the way the front end loads. One of the ways I have had some success is embedding styles into the HTML page.

I am planning on embedding all the JavaScript and CSS into the webpage. The problem is the backend program loads multiple activities of my Front End throughout a typical user experience. This is just the way it works.

Do these separate activities load my linked CSS/JavaScript files from a cache? If they do, will it make it pointless for me to embed all the CSS/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways of doing it is to shift all the script tags to the last line of the body. So that the body of the page gets loaded first and then the scripts would load causing lesser delay.